# Targeted Request in postman.setNextRequest() can't set Environment Variables

Tags: postman

I use `postman.setNextRequest("login")` to call login request. Inside login test I set environment variables from token login response. It's not work. Login testing is success, but environment variable token not exists.

*Pre Request Script in Collection:*

```
var email = "foo@bar.com";
var password = "mypassword";
pm.environment.set("email", email); // success to set env variable
pm.environment.set("password", password); // success to set env variable
postman.setNextRequest("login");
postman.setNextRequest(null);
```

*Test Script in **login** request:*

```
pm.test("Status code is 200", function () {
    pm.response.to.have.status(200);
    var dt = pm.response.json();
    pm.environment.set("token", dt.token); // failed to set env variable
});
```

Comment: Why do you have the second SetNextRequest in the script? Does the work flow even use the first one if you have something there that ends the flows in the same place. Check out point 2 https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/scripts/branching_and_looping

Comment: if I not set `postman.setNextRequest(null);` in the last script, login request will be call continously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolve this problem by enabled **Persist Variables** checkbox in Collection Runner before run collection.